# .desktop file doesn't show icon

Tags: icons, .desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Event Manager
Exec=python3 /media/PRIVATE/Document/Python/Reminder\ ver\ 2/Gui.py
Icon="/home/dtoan/Pictures/book Reader.png"
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;
```

This is my .desktop file that I created. But in dash, it shows a default icon instead of my png image. I'm sure the path is correct. Any idea?

Comment: Remove the quotes. Unlike the Exec= line, spaces are not an issue.

Comment: I did it already, but because of low reputation or whatever, it doesn't show.

Comment: Haha, thanks, but I think you upovoted :).  Accepting is ticking the big V. The green mark then appears, no matter your reputation. Don't worry, thanks anyway.

Comment: Reviewers: This is *not* off-topic. This is about a syntax error arising from the original poster *not knowing what syntax to use*, not a typo. It can continue helping other users and, judging by the number of votes on the question and answer, probably already has helped many.

Answer (score 13):

Short answer:

Remove the quotes in:

```
Icon="/home/dtoan/Pictures/book Reader.png"
```

Unlike the `Exec`= line, spaces should be left alone in the `Icon=` line.

Apart from everything, I wouldn't use spaces in a name in general.

Comment: Omg, thank you very much. Can't believe this tiny problem took me hours.